# I'm watching an anime and don't recognise one of the characters. Can I ask who he is?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

I'm aware that this site no longer accepts anime ID questions, but I'm also aware that there are exceptions: merchandise items, for example, or songs. I have a question that's sort of an ID question, but I don't know which side of the line it falls on.

I've just finished *My Hero Academia* S3. There's a character in one of the intros that, as far as I can tell, never actually appears in the series, and I want to post a question asking who he is. I have a screenshot of him, but I don't believe the question would count as an image-only ID request because I already know what series he's from and the screenshot is just to illustrate who/what I'm asking about.

**Would this question be on-topic?** If not, it's no biggie, I can just ask SciFi.SE instead. I just figured the users here would be more likely to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Asking to ID characters or other elements within a known series are still on-topic

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I'll go ahead and ask the question.