# What identification requests are acceptable here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?

Tags: support, faq, identification-questions

I remember/saw/heard something from an anime/manga/other media, but I don't know what it is.

However, it seems this site doesn't accept some kinds of identification requests:

- **Story-based/image identification** (2016): [What we'd like to do about those gosh darn "identification requests" questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions)
- **Music identification** (2022): [So it's about time we (finally) deprecated music ID-request questions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/so-its-about-time-we-finally-deprecated-music-id-request-questions)

What can I get identified here? Otherwise, where else can I possibly get helped with it?

---

<sup>Inspired from [How can I find the title of a movie from just a description or image? -- Movies & TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129)</sup>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### First of all...

Anime & Manga Stack Exchange still accepts some kinds of identification requests, *particularly if the series is known*:

1. [Characters from a known series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4187/im-watching-an-anime-and-dont-recognise-one-of-the-characters-can-i-ask-who-h)
2. Episodes from a known series (this includes some anime/manga-style series of non-Japanese origin)
3. Cosplay/merchandise/*itasha*, [but with some exceptions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/are-questions-regarding-cosplay-or-anime-related-items-still-on-topic)

*Note that this list is not intended to be exhaustive*. The above list contains the types that are *known to be acceptable* by the community.

If you are still not sure if your identification request is acceptable here, feel free to [post a new discussion on the meta](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion,identification-questions) (requires 5 reputation). If you have enough reputation to [participate in chat](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (requires 20 reputation), feel free to join our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697). Otherwise, just [ask the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and the community will evaluate it naturally.

---

#### But wait...

- If the series has *some sci-fi/fantasy elements*, our sister site [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) accepts it, **whether it is a [series identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) or [music identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11486/36437)**.
- For a more general *manga*/(light) novel, our sister site [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) accepts it, but **please ensure to follow the guidelines on [the tag info](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and [their meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/guidelines-for-good-story-id-questions) first!**
- If you have an image of an anime/manga/character, try doing a reverse image search: [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618)
- If you feel adventurous, you can also try searching through various databases based on criteria such as genre, etc.: [What databases and listing sites exist for anime, manga, etc?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696)

---

#### Otherwise...

- **MyAnimeList** has [anime identification](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?board=1) and [manga identification](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?board=2) threads
- [**Animesuki Forums**](https://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?t=11904) for general anime/manga/game identification help
- [**Baka-Updates Manga**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/topics.php?fid=10373) for anime & manga identification
- **Reddit** has some subreddits like:

  - [/r/anime](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime), [/r/Animesuggest](https://www.reddit.com/r/Animesuggest/), [/r/manga](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga), [/r/tipofmytongue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/) for anime & manga identification.
  - [r/japanesemusic](https://www.reddit.com/r/japanesemusic/?f=flair_name%3A%22Help%22) for song identification.

  but *please read the rules on the sidebar of each respective subreddit beforehand!*
- **Quora** has ['Anime Identification' topic](https://www.quora.com/topic/Anime-Identification)
- **TV Tropes** has ["You Know That Show..."](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/query.php?type=ykts)
- [**Trace.moe**](https://trace.moe) is a search engine for connecting screenshots to anime series

Comment: To-do: add alternative resources for music ID. Feel free to [edit] and add them to the list!